# Who should decide to raise alerts, a central server or satellite servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, logic, monitoring, alert

I have come across an architectural design problem and I am not sure which is the best way to proceed.  My dichotomy is do I put alerting logic on the remote satellites, or collect information from the satellites to a central server and put the alerting logic there.

We have many satellite automation systems that sometimes need to raise alerts, both inside the automation application for problems with automation, and for problems from the sysadmin side of things that could cause issues with the system itself (disk space, database size etc).  Each satellite is itself quite a powerful system (Core i5, 4GB RAM), but we are hoping to downgrade this to an ARM based system (hopefully an RPi) with the next design iteration.  We have full control over the software on the satellite systems.

There is a central server (currently running Rails and Observium) which receives the alerts and sends them out to SMS and/or email.  Information is collected from system agents (Check_MK/Observium) and stored on the central server but currently just for reporting/tracking purposes.  The Observium alerting however is not suitable or flexible enough for our needs.

I am wondering what the pros and cons are of putting alerting logic on the central server, as opposed to putting it on the remote satellites because no doubt someone has come across this problem before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it really depends on the answers of these questions:

**1) How critical it is for you to have guaranteed delivery of these messages?**

Having the satellites send their messages directly, without relying on the central server may be more reliable since you skip a communication step.

**2) How likely are you to need to modify the process in the future?**

Instead of SMS/email, imagine you suddenly need to invoke a service that creates a ticket on each alert in some new support system in the future. Or you might have to modify the text of the messages to add some more info. If you put this logic in the satellites, you will have to update all of them. This might be worse in terms of maintainability. If you cover this in your central server, it might be easier. Having the logic centralized means all configuration is also centralized.

**3) Is it more logical to make the server or the satellites responsible for notification delivery?**

Think about separation of concerns here - does it make sense for the satellite to be concerned with the technical details of sending eMails/SMSs? Most likely not.

Hope this helps!

Plamen